# Angular directive for holderjs - expression evaluation not working as intended

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to use the excellent [holderjs](http://holderjs.com) library in an angular2 project. Someone [wrote up](https://github.com/aogriffiths/angular-2-holderjs) a very simple attribute directive which I am trying to use.

holderjs is basically a client side image placeholder generator.

I am trying to modify the directive so that I can pass dynamic placeholders.

For example, this works:

```
<img holderjs data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto">
```

But these don't:

```
<img holderjs data-src="{{myvariable}}"> 
<img holderjs [data-src]="myvariable">
```

The angular directive is really a simple wrapper that runs Holderjs inside it. I've tried moving the code to ngOnInit as well as tried to specify `data-src` as an `@Input` but haven't had success so far.

Any ideas? I've set up a plunker to demonstrate the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/ibOyJvmNWadQWOm6Ki7u?p=info

The code is in home.page.ts & html

The core problem is holderjs inserts a `src` img tag based on the URL provided in `data-src` but when using either expression evaluation or binding (adding an @Input to the directive), the src tag doesn't get created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know two things about your problem:

- Anguler is stripping the `data-` prefix in the compiler (the idea behind this was that people could prefix non-standard attributes with bindings) so you have to use attribute binding looking something like:

  `attr.data-src="{{myvariable}}"`or `[attr.data-src]="myvariable"`
- Attribute binding won't be appeared until ngAfterViewInit is called therefore you should fire your plugin inside ngAfterViewInit hook:

**holderjs.directive.ts**

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[holderjs]',
})
export class HolderjsDirective {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     Holder.run({images:this.el.nativeElement});
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BojnVXkdJRHI6erbLdwN?p=preview)**

Comment: YOU. ARE. THE. MAN ! thank you. Been at this since yesterday!